# text is coming in a single line in dialog box

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

i am not able to handle the white space from a data coming from DB

the code is below :

```
<td class="tdx" bgcolor="#CCCCCC" style="" id="sol" style="background-color:white;border-style:ridge;white-space: pre-wrap">
    <div class="dialog">
        <p>
            <%=solution%>
        </p>
    </div>
    <button class="opener">Open Dialog</button>
</td>
```

the `<%=solution%>` is coming from DB is coming in a single line . i have also included the pre-wrap in CSS

jquery-code :

```
$(function() {

    $('.opener').each(function() {
        var dialog = $(this).prev('.dialog').dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            show: {
                effect: "blind",
                duration: 1000
            },
            hide: {
                effect: "explode",
                duration: 1000
            }
        });

        $(this).click(function() {
            dialog.dialog("open");
        });
    });
});
```

if i dont use dialog box and retrieve the text in text area ... **it is coming good**

**NODE** --> pre wrap is working good in fiddle

image added

[image]

Comment: can you view the source and post the html that is pulled from the db

Comment: the data from DB is in a single line

Comment: yes but is it html encoded as in does it have &nbsp; and other such elements?

Comment: no i dont see such element

Comment: added an image for detail

Comment: ok, now I see the error - you have a long web address.  Venkatesh's answer should solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

```
dialog p{
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

add above code to your css.

Answer (score 0):

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ToddMark/ab02xkp4/)

You can use these code to achieve what you want.

```
p{
    width: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
    -ms-text-overflow: ellipsis;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The most possible reason is wrong CSS selector.
Try something like this:

```
#dialog p { white-space: pre-wrap; }
```

As UI uses div#dialog as wrapper for dialog content